# Async .eachLimit callback Error not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I the following code in my node.js project.

```
async.eachLimit(dbresult, 1, function (record, callback) {
  var json = JSON.stringify(record)
  var form = new FormData()
  form.append('data', json)
  form.submit(cfg.server + '/external/api', function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
     callback(err)
    }
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
      connection.query('UPDATE selected_photos set synced = 1 WHERE selected_id = "' + record.selected_id + '"', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          callback(err)
        } else {
         callback()
        }
      })
    } else {
      console.log(res.statusCode)
    return callback(err)
    } 
  })
}, function (err) {
// if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
if (err) {
   // One of the iterations produced an error.
   // All processing will now stop.
   console.log('A share failed to process. Try rerunning the Offline Sync')
     process.exit(0)
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully')
      process.exit(0)
    }
 })
}
```

res.statusCode = 302 So this should error out. But the the error callback is never triggered. How do it get it to trigger the error so that it stops eachLimit and the shows the

```
console.log('A share failed to process. Try rerunning the Offline Sync')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

`if (err) {`

in first line of form submit handler. After that, you are sure that there was no error. So when you check response `statusCode` and try to call back with error, you are calling back with empty value.
That is why you do not get error when checking for it in your final callback function.

Try to create `new Error('Status not OK: ' + res.statusCode)` when calling back from your form submit handler.

Comment: That got me close. I did: console.log(res.statusCode)
                      err = Error('Status not OK: ' + res.statusCode)
                      callback(err)